# How to Do Exponential Step Iteration in bpy.props.IntProperty()?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm trying to create a custom UI menu that allow to user to click in a bpy.props.IntProperty(). But I want that step of each iteration in the UI menu show 2^click.

[image]

For example:

```
class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_int : bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "N", soft_min= 0, soft_max=2048, step=2)
```

This code will generate [0,2,4,6,8,10...] (n+2) for each click

I want [1,2,4,8,16,32,64...] (2^n) for each click

Is it possible?

Comment: There's another solution here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288967/bpy-use-integer-property-with-exponential-increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I made a sample panel with an increment/decrement stepper component that increments values of within power of 2. Apologies for the global variable hack. Anyone feel free to edit and use a proper member variable and please test before editing. You can also input any value and it will automatically get the closest 2^N value. Anyway this is for demonstration purpose.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel, PropertyGroup, Scene, WindowManager
from bpy.props import IntProperty, PointerProperty
from math import log, ceil, floor

def closest_exponent(x):
    possible_results = floor(log(x, 2)), ceil(log(x, 2))
    power = min(possible_results, key= lambda z: abs(x-2**z))
    return power

def closest_exponential_value(x):
    return 2**closest_exponent(x)

curr_value = 1

class MYTEST_PT_Panel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "MYTEST_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "MY UI"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "MY TEST"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        placeholder = context.scene.placeholder
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(placeholder, "inc_dec_int", text="stepper", slider=False)


class MyPropertyGroup(PropertyGroup):

    def update_value(self, context):
        global curr_value
        current = curr_value
        curr_value = bpy.context.scene.placeholder.inc_dec_int
        inc = current < curr_value
        
        if curr_value in (current, 1,2):
            curr_value = closest_exponential_value(curr_value)
            return

        if abs(current - curr_value) > 1:
            curr_value = closest_exponential_value(curr_value)
            bpy.context.scene.placeholder.inc_dec_int = curr_value
        elif inc:
            power = closest_exponent(current)
            bpy.context.scene.placeholder.inc_dec_int = 2**(power+1)
        else:
            power = closest_exponent(current)
            bpy.context.scene.placeholder.inc_dec_int = 2**(power-1)
        curr_value = bpy.context.scene.placeholder.inc_dec_int

    inc_dec_int: IntProperty(
        min=1,
        default=1,
        step=1,
        update = update_value
    )

classes = (
    MyPropertyGroup,
    MYTEST_PT_Panel,
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
    Scene.placeholder = PointerProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
    del Scene.placeholder

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Perfect, solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288967/blender-python-module-bpy-use-integer-property-with-exponential-increment/288973#288973) is more efficient