# setter in bpy.props.StringPropery not working

Tags: properties

I'm having a lot of trouble using the setter in a `StringProperty`

I simply want that, when a value is set to filter, to remove the spaces on both sides.

The definition:

```
filter : bpy.props.StringProperty(default="", set=set_filter)
```

And the set method:

```
def set_filter(self, value):
    # self.filter = value.strip()
    self["filter"] = value.strip() # Documentation says is like that
```

However, none of them work. The property is empty after setting a value. Any one has an idea?

Comment: Try adding a getter too.

Comment: @scurest wow! It worked. I would have never try that ._. Thank you so much for the help friend! It was driving me crazy

Comment: I had the same problem [before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/288973/88681). I've filed a bug for it: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/107671.

Comment: What a coincidence. Thanks for reporting the issue and the help mate :)